# How can you use last_insert_rowid to insert multiple rows?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Let's say I have a database with two tables `Persons` and `PhoneNumbers`, where the `PhoneNumbers` table has a foreign key to `Persons`. If I want to insert a person with a phone number in a single transaction, I can write a query like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO Persons(Name) VALUES(...);
INSERT INTO PhoneNumbers(PersonForeignKey, Number) VALUES(last_insert_rowid(), ...);
END TRANSACTION;
```

But what if I want to insert a person with multiple phone numbers? The obvious way:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO Persons(Name) VALUES(...);
INSERT INTO PhoneNumbers(PersonForeignKey, Number) VALUES(last_insert_rowid(), ...);
INSERT INTO PhoneNumbers(PersonForeignKey, Number) VALUES(last_insert_rowid(), ...);
INSERT INTO PhoneNumbers(PersonForeignKey, Number) VALUES(last_insert_rowid(), ...);
END TRANSACTION;
```

won't work, of course, because for the second phone number, `last_insert_rowid()` will return the rowid of the first phone number instead of the person.

Is there a way to do this using basic SQL (SQLite, specifically)?

**Conclusion**

Apparently, there is no direct way to do this. I've made a few benchmarks with @Michal Powaga's suggestions and a few other ideas based on temporary tables, and the fastest way to do it seems to be something like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Insert_PhoneNumbers(PersonForeignKey INTEGER, PhoneNumber VARCHAR);
DELETE FROM Insert_PhoneNumbers;
INSERT INTO Insert_PhoneNumbers(PhoneNumber) VALUES ('Phone 1');
INSERT INTO Insert_PhoneNumbers(PhoneNumber) VALUES ('Phone 2');

INSERT INTO Persons(Name) VALUES(...);

UPDATE Insert_PhoneNumbers SET PersonForeignKey=last_insert_rowid();

INSERT INTO PhoneNumbers(PersonForeignKey, Number)
   SELECT PersonForeignKey, PhoneNumber
   FROM Insert_PhoneNumbers
```

creating and updating a temporary table seems to be very fast (compared to queries on the Persons or PhoneNumbers-tables) and the insert speed won't depend on the number of persons/phone numbers already in the database, so that's the solution I chose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store last_insert_rowid() after person insertion to temporary table or this might work too:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO Persons(Name) VALUES(...);

INSERT INTO PhoneNumbers(PersonForeignKey, Number) 
VALUES(last_insert_rowid(), 'number 1');

INSERT INTO PhoneNumbers(PersonForeignKey, Number) 
SELECT PersonForeignKey, 'number 2' 
FROM PhoneNumbers where PhonePrimaryKey = last_insert_rowid();

INSERT INTO PhoneNumbers(PersonForeignKey, Number) 
SELECT PersonForeignKey, 'number 3' 
FROM PhoneNumbers where PhonePrimaryKey = last_insert_rowid();

END TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: Thanks, I never thought about using a temporary table!

Comment: You can use foreign key from last inserted row as I've referring to its primary key. It looks even nicer (I think) but works only for cases like this one described in your question. Temporary table is more flexible.

Comment: @nikie, sorry I didn't notice your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work, although it is far from ideal:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO Persons(Name) VALUES(...);
    INSERT INTO PhoneNumbers(PersonForeignKey, Number) VALUES(last_insert_rowid(), ...);
    INSERT INTO PhoneNumbers(PersonForeignKey, Number) SELECT PersonForeignKey, 123 WHERE PhoneNumberRowId = last_insert_rowid()
    INSERT INTO PhoneNumbers(PersonForeignKey, Number) SELECT PersonForeignKey, 456 WHERE PhoneNumberRowId = last_insert_rowid()
END TRANSACTION;
```

Not brilliant, but basically you are chaining the last row ID to get the original primary key.

Comment: I don't think I understand your answer. Did you read the question or just the title?